# Where is the negative sign coming from in the distributive step

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I came across a proof in the Book Quantum Computer for Computer Scientists. It shows the derivation of the equation for the division of complex numbers. I am trying to follow. It starts with
$$
(x,y) = \frac{(a_{1}, b_{1})}{(a_{2}, b_{2})}
$$
where a1, b1 represent the real and imaginary part of a complex number c1. Likewise for a2 and b2. The next step in the proof says:

> then by definition of division as the inverse of multiplication
> $$
> (a_{1}, b_{1}) = (x,y) \times (a_{2}, b_{2})
> $$

which I understand fine, but then it says

> or
> $$
> (a_{1}, b_{1}) = (a_{2}x - b_{2}y, a_{2}y + b_{2}x)
> $$

My question is where does that (-) come from? everything is positive. I expect it to be:
$$
(a_{1}, b_{1}) = (a_{2}x + b_{2}y, a_{2}y + b_{2}x)
$$
I am guessing my understanding of how multiplication works here is wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: $iy\times ib_2=-b_2y$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That negative sign comes from $i^2=-1$.

$(a_2+ib_2)(x+iy)=a_2x+ia_2y+ib_2x+\color{blue}{i^2}b_2y=(a_2x\color{blue}-b_2y)+i(a_2y+b_2x)$.